# express.Router hitting 404 instead of route when separated in own files

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am having trouble understanding weird express.Router() behaviour.
I decided to tidy up my routes to enable better API versioning.
If I keep simpler structure like below, everything works as expected :

**app.js**

```
app.use('/v1', v1);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

**v1.js (api version / api index file)**

```
module.exports = router;
router.post('/orders',    auth.isUser, OrderController.create);
router.get('/orders',     auth.isUser, OrderController.getAll);
router.get('/orders/:id', auth.isUser, OrderController.get);
router.put('/orders/:id', auth.isEmployee, OrderController.update);
```

but if I move these routes to a separate file, export Router and import it as below:

**ordersRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const OrderController = require('../controllers/OrderController');

module.exports = router;

// routes for endpoint
// hostname/v1/orders/*
router.post(    '/orders',        auth.isUser, OrderController.create);
router.get(     '/orders',        auth.isUser, OrderController.getAll);
router.get(     '/orders/:id',    auth.isUser, OrderController.get);
router.put(     '/orders/:id',    auth.isEmployee, OrderController.update);
```

**v1.js**

```
const router              = express.Router();
const ordersRoutes = require('./ordersRoutes');

module.exports = router;

router.use( '/orders',     ordersRoutes         );
```

I hit 404 on every order route, which is weird because the same approach with other file works just fine (I compared them many times... :( ). My assumption is that it has to do with too many instances of Router or maybe ordering of routes, but I cant put my finger on it. Any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js, next(err) function forcing other routes to response an 404 error. You should remove err argument from function.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't 404 route only be hit if no others match (it's set up as last one)? As I mentioned, When I use flatter route structure, it works.